# What is the difference between these two methods of batching with stateful LSTM

Tags: neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

With stateful LSTM, are these two methods effectively the same:

```
batch_input_shape = [1,10,2]
for _ in range(3):
    x_batch, y_batch = batcher()
    model.train_on_batch(x_batch, y_batch)
model.reset_states()
```

and

```
batch_input_shape = [3,10,2]
x_batch, y_batch = batcher()
model.train_on_batch(x_batch, y_batch)
model.reset_states()
```

i.e. the first method 30 rows of data spread across 3 separate batches of 10 sequences and `reset_states()` called after all 3 `train_on_batch()` calls. The second method 30 rows of data submitted in a batch of 3 with 10 sequences, and `reset_states()` called immediately after.

Assuming it all the same data, and putting aside training times (first method will take longer) is the end result the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, they are the same. The state is carried over between batches, so submitting 3 batches of 10 to make 30 is the same as submitting one batch of 30.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21388485)

Comment: Still, this should be part of the question, not an answer.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. I think I know what question *I* was asking, unless you know differently? I asked if the two methods produced the same end result - it's literally the very thing I asked.